# well system pressure stops after a couple minutes

Tags: plumbing

We had a new well tank installed a year ago. We hoped that water pressure will improve.  Recently, I have noticed that pressure will start then stop for several seconds and return.  Tank pressure is within the required range.

We have no filters on our system. Could that be an issue?   We recently moved in our house. Water pressure stinks even with new tank.  Can we clean /purge and add a filter pre storage tank? What is the standard protocol?  I am very handy and  capable of doing basic repairs.

I would love to improve the water pressure, but mainly provide basic constant pressure.  Thank you for any help that you can extend.

Comment: Can you clarify your question and define what pressure will start then stop is telling us. It appears water is flowing out at a fixed rate.  With the pressure stopping to rise then starting again could be serious trouble and the well is running out of water or you are taking  out to much. If this is true I will guess and say your pump is in the well and you cannot hear it cavating.  Your pump will cycle with the pressure switch set points is this what is happening? A picture might help. As far as pressure that is controlled by the pressure switch, not the tank. These are adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a well with a pressure vessel "big grey metal cylinder" it has a  bag in it. It sound like water has gotten in its pressure zone just bleed that area its usually  the top not of the vessel